# Error : String was not recognised as a valid date time

Tags: c#, mysql

when i am trying to connect c# code to mysql database there is a mistake in date datatype

```
try
{
      CultureInfo CultureInfoDateCulture = new CultureInfo("ja-JP");
      DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(accountend, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfoDateCulture);
      return true;
}
catch
{
      return false;
}
```

when i have to collect date from the month calender i have used this validation for MYSQL and the datatype i have used is DATE datatpe

I have been getting the folllowing error

```
String was not recognised as a valid date time
```

please help me guys.... Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of `accountend`?

Comment: it is retrievd from the date calender i.e 4/11/2014 @pravprab

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL Date Format is `yyyy-MM-dd` so you should use the same format while parsing it in  the `DateTime.ParseExact()` method.

Try This:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(accountend, "yyyy-MM-dd", 
                                                         CultureInfoDateCulture);
```

**EDIT :** From Your Comments your Date Format is   `M/d/yyyy`

Try This:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(accountend, "M/d/yyyy", 
                                                         CultureInfoDateCulture);
```

Comment: i have tried that but no use same error any other suggestion please..........thanks for the reply @Sudhakar Tillapudi

Comment: @user3531533: can you please debug your code and check what is the exact value of `accountid`?

Comment: yeah Sure its its taken from date calender 5/2/2014

Comment: @user3531533: is first 5 is date or month?

Comment: here 5 is considered as month

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.ParseExact requires that the format string represent accurately the day, month and year of the string that need to be converted

So assuming that your date string is  `4/11/2014`  (`day, month, year`) you need

```
try
{
      CultureInfo CultureInfoDateCulture = new CultureInfo("ja-JP");
      DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(accountend, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfoDateCulture);
      return true;
}
catch
{
      return false;
}
```

instead if the format is `month, day, year`, the format string is

```
 DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(accountend, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfoDateCulture);
```

By the way, your date is in the format expected by the InvariantCulture, so you could avoid the creation of the CultureInfo in this context, it is enough to use

```
 DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(accountend, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Sorry 4 indicates month i.e 11 is date and 4 is month @Steve

Comment: Not a problem, just change the order of MM/dd

Comment: @Steve: instead of double `dd` and `MM` single d and M is fine as OP's date has only single digit for single day and month

Comment: What is the problem?, you should have the datetime variable correctly set up or do you have still errors?

Comment: That's strange, I can convert without a problem here. `string accountend = "4/11/2014"` with  the CultureInfo CultureInfoDateCulture or with the InvariantCulture

Comment: Sorry STEVE for making you trouble i am new new to both c# and mysql but i have to complete this with in tommorow...can u send me in detail    what should i do @Steve

Comment: I can't help you more, there is just a simple error in the format string used to convert the string to a date. You should check if the string obtained by the calendar is really a M/d/yyyy then the code above should work. Try to use the debugger, set a breakpoint just before the conversion and examine the input passed to ParseExact

Comment: Yeah steve I debugged and format is m/d/yyyy @Steve